# How to send FCM Push Notification using PHP?

Tags: php, firebase, curl, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have the below code where I am trying to send FCM push notification to an android app targetting specific device. In terminal upon running php push.php I get no result and no errors too.

Please help me what is wrong here, I am able to send using the legacy FCM APIs but I could not using HTTP v1

```
<?php
$serviceAccount = json_decode(file_get_contents('privatekey.json'), true);

$serverKey = $serviceAccount['private_key'];
$projectId = $serviceAccount['project_id'];

$data = [
    'message' => [
        'token' => 'd6dYpnaLSP2zRk4o6dFfFZ:APA91bG-ZB7XFB-01K54cEVAiyMuqbKyBGhYX-XeiR2QcC3QKv1-MXI4wAy_cwL-d1TLNOUkF-pqt0WQed4b2VcL8OeBxXOPVwrMiWv69TkDRRidOPUw_YjA-ISsgCNoxlWUIb5V_PV6',
        'notification' => [
            'title' => 'Your Title',
            'body' => 'Your Message',
        ],
    ],
];

$headers = [
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $serverKey,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/notifizy/messages:send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


echo $result;
?>
```

I have tried all, legacy FCM API works but not this.

Answer (score 0):

//  Android app targeting specific device you need RECIVER_TOKEN
// and get your SERVER API KEY and follow below code

```
 <?php
    define('SERVER_API_KEY', 'MYSERVERAPIKEY'); 
    $data = array(
       "to" => "$RECIVER_TOKEN",
       "notification" => array(
           "title" => "Test-Title",
           "body" => "Test-Message")
        );
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: key=' . SERVER_API_KEY
    );
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        echo 'FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
       die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    
    echo $result;
    ?>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to implement Push notification in PHP

```html
<?php 
    function send_notification ($tokens, $message_complete)
    {

        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $tokens,
            'notification' => $message_complete
        );
        $headers = array('Authorization:key=[PUT YOUR KEY HERE]','Content-Type: application/json');
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);           
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }

    if($_POST){
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $image = $_POST['image'];
        $msg = array
        (
            'title' => $title,
            'body' => $message,
            'image' => $image,
            'url' => 'https://www.google.com',
            'icon' => $image,
            'vibrate' => 1,
            'sound' => 1
        );
        $tokens = array();
        if(isset($_POST['send_test'])) {
            $tokens = $test_token;
            $message_type = "Test";
        } elseif(isset($_POST['send_live'])){
            $tokens[] = $member_token;
            $message_type = "Live";
        }
        $message_complete = $msg;
        $message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message_complete);
        echo "<p class='messageBox'>Push Notification has been sent!</p>" . $message_status;
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($tokens);
    }else{
        $tokenV = unserialize($_POST['tokensValue']);
    }
```